# How can I download scaled down version of an image?

Tags: java, android

I need to download images that are very large 5mb+.

I am aware of scaling the image before displaying it to save phone memory but the problem of downloading a large image still remains.

How can I download, say, a 50% scaled down version of an image rather than downloading a full image then scaling it?

Comment: From where you are downloading images ?. From your server or from any other places ?

Comment: @kartik imgur.com mainly

Comment: @user521180 then you need to fetch the URL for the thumbnails. How are you getting the URL for the full pictures?

Comment: @dvorak manually. I have a list of urls

Comment: so, the question is, "given an imgur.com URL to a full-scale picture, derive the URL to its thumbnail at 50% size"?

Comment: @dvorak pretty much yes. although '50%' is just an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be supported by the server from which you download.

If the server is not yours, you need to look up that server's documentation (or reverse-engineer).

If the server is yours, it depends on the used technology. Look up an image manipulation library for that particular server-side technology you are using.

---

in case of imgur.com,

look here: http://api.imgur.com/

Imgur lets you make 500 calls per hour per IP, or 1000 if you are registered. Uploads count tenfold.

The metadata about an image is documented here: http://api.imgur.com/resources_anon#image_hash . Access either `api.imgur.com/2/image/[hash].xml` or `api.imgur.com/2/image/[hash].json`, and pick either `image.links.small_square` (90x90) or `image.links.large_thumbnail` (?x640) from the response. Note that imgur also generates thumbnails (160x160) for its home page. URLs for these seem to be `i.imgur.com/[hash]b.jpg`

The link to the large image is `i.imgur.com/[hash].jpg`, so if your link is `http://i.imgur.com/xDpEF.jpg` or `http://imgur.com/xDpEF`, then `xDpEF` is the hash you need.

Answer (score 2):

It is NOT possible to download a scaled down version of some image when the web server does not provide a scaled down version.

You'll need to scale them in the web/on the server, where you host them. So the question is not java/android, but on the webserver, and depends on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, unless your server supports scaling down the image before you download it. If the server doesn't have that option, your best option is to scale it down while you read the image from the stream, using BitmapFactory.Options inSampleSize.

Answer (score 0):

Sir it is impossible because if you are downloading it from any server then server must have the scaled image in many forms like 50% scale or 25% scaled. So it is possible only when the server is maintained by you from where you are downloading the image and at backend you have provided some method to scale the image.

If you are downloading the image from any server then is is not possible to get scaled image from server without any backend procedure to scale image.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download the image to a file, then use `BitmapFactory` with `BitmapFactory.Options` to determine the size of the image.  From the image size, calculate how much you want to scale it, and again use `BitmapFactory` (with `Options`) to load a scaled version of the image.

Comment: doesn't solve the problem of having to download a large image, which is the point of this question.

Comment: It is an approach to solving the problem by saving the image file as a local file, and then scaling it appropriately.

Comment: quoting the question second paragraph: "I am aware of scaling the image before displaying it to save phone memory but the problem of downloading a large image still remains."

Answer (score 0):

It depends on Server, Server should support scaling down the image.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers there is one solution that may work without special software on server side;

If the images are stored on the server in JPEG format and uses the  interlaced / progressive mode you would be able to download them partially for creating a thumb nail.

This special mode was designed to see a preview-image while it is still downloading. Compacting the preview image could result in an image that can be used as a thumbnail.

However I don't know a library that would support thumbnail loading this way.