# How to reduce image quality when using Universal Image Loader?

Tags: android, image, universal-image-loader

I'm using Universal Image Loader and I have to load 17 images from this page http://www.mangareader.net/detective-conan/898 then display it into ViewPager. However, images load very slow so I want to reduce the image quality and size for performance. What should I do to improve the speed?
Thanks.

Comment: use picasa...try it once instead of image loader

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not posible to download a scaled down version of image if the server does not supprt that feature. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176129/how-can-i-download-scaled-down-version-of-an-image).

One soltion to this is you can cache images when you run it for the first time. And next time check if the image is available in cache or not. if it is present in cache, get it from device else download it and cache it.

Answer (score 1):

use BitmapConfigARGB_4444

```
DisplayImageOptions profilepicOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                               .showStubImage(R.drawable.user_pic).cacheInMemory()
                               .cacheOnDisc().bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444).build();
```